# I cannot set data attribute of button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to set the value of a data attribute in a button but somehow it doesn't work.

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/4gwAS/1/

My code:

```
    <div id="parent">

    <div id="rating" data-score="5">5 STARS</div>
    <button id="store_score">store rating in save button</button>

    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button save_rating"
                    data-score=""
                    data-organisor_id="12"
                    data-event_id="23">save rating</a>

    </div>

$('#store_score').on('click', function() {
        var score = $('#rating').data('score'); //getter
        alert(score);
        $(this).parent().find('.save_rating').data('score', score);

    });
```

I need to address the class of the save button and cannot work with an id here.

Any idea why the data-score attribute of the "save rating"-button does not get set?

Comment: It is working.. http://jsfiddle.net/4gwAS/3/

Comment: how do you know it's not working, i did a alert for data and it's giving me 4.

Comment: `$(this).parent().find('.save_rating').attr('data-score',score); `
[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4gwAS/1/)

Comment: It does get set, but you're alerting the `#rating.data-score` instead of `.save_rating.data-score`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have got bad tag name in your code. Your tag is not called `score`, its `data-score`.

So if you want change your `data-score` attribute after button is pressed, try this:

```
 $(this).parent().find('.save_rating').attr('data-score', 4);
```

**[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/4gwAS/2/)**

Comment: I don't think, thats working. Try to view source code then push the button. The attribute data-score will not changed and I think, that this is the thing, what asker need to.

Comment: who said that the source would get affected while using `.data()`..? You should have explained about the usage of `.data()` tag.. Instead you have suggested a kind of wrong way to the OP.. That is replacing the `.data()` with `.attr()`

Comment: but he want set that `attr()` :) Look at the last block of his question :)